# Как сделать такой же просмотр видео?

Tags: javascript, html

На сайте нашел очень интересный внешний вид просмотра видео. Не как не разберусь через что он реализован.  http://happylab.ru/ Сайт сделан на cms drupal. Прошу помощи.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду видео на фоне или видео, всплывающее по клику на кнопке?

Comment: По клику, в портфолио

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)

Это JQuery плагин, не зависит от CMS.

Он реализует нужный функционал, остается лишь настроить как выглядят кнопки (картинки поменять).

На сайте всплываха реализована через [JQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Answer (score 0):

> нашел очень интересный внешний вид просмотра видео

Фоновое видео что ли?

```html
<div class="video-bg-wrapper">
    <video id="video-bg" class="video-bg visible-lg" src="/sites/all/themes/happylab/images/main_video.mp4" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload="auto" width="100%" height="auto">
    <img src="/sites/all/themes/happylab/images/main_bg.jpg" alt="">
    </video>
    <img class="hidden-lg" src="/sites/all/themes/happylab/images/main_bg.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

В потфолио это вставка с vimeo.com

```html
<div id="player" class="player player-eee092a8-b3ec-4c86-84b2-149d50e8e231 js-player-fullscreen with-fullscreen with-sticky-custom-logo"><div class="video-wrapper"><div class="video" data-thumb="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/497490516.jpg?mw=900&amp;mh=720" data-thumb-width="900" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/497490516.jpg?mw=900&amp;mh=720&quot;);"><div class="telecine invisible"><video preload="metadata" src="https://15-lvl3-pdl.vimeocdn.com/01/2499/4/112497086/310570745.mp4?expires=1485550771&amp;token=0f2d7333ac6b86afd504d"></video></div></div></div><div class="target hidden" hidden=""></div><div class="captions hidden with-controls" aria-live="assertive" style="font-size: 31px;" hidden=""></div><div class="outro-wrapper hidden" hidden=""><div class="outro" role="dialog" aria-live="assertive"></div></div><div class="controls-wrapper"><div class="title" role="contentinfo"><header>  <div class="portrait" aria-hidden="true"> <a tabindex="-1" href="https://vimeo.com/happylabru" target="_blank"> <img src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/9159859_60x60.jpg" alt="" width="60" height="60"> </a> </div>  <div class="headers">  <h1> <a href="https://vimeo.com/112497086" target="_blank" data-clip-link="">Волшебство от Happylab</a> </h1>  <div class="sub-title"><h2 class="byline-from">от <a href="https://vimeo.com/happylabru" target="_blank">Happylab creative agency</a></h2>  </div>  </div></header></div><div class="controls"><button class="play rounded-box state-paused" title="Воспроизвести" data-title-play="Воспроизвести" data-title-pause="Пауза" aria-label="Воспроизвести"><div class="tiny-bars"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 65 40"><defs><clipPath id="rounded-border"><rect height="100%" width="100%" x="0" y="0" rx="5"/></clipPath> <pattern id="tiny-buffer" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 10 10"><line x1="5" y1="-1" x2="-5" y2="10" stroke-width="2" stroke="#666" stroke-linecap="butt"/><line x1="10" y1="-1" x2="0" y2="10" stroke-width="2" stroke="#666" stroke-linecap="butt"/><line x1="15" y1="-1" x2="5" y2="10" stroke-width="2" stroke="#666" stroke-linecap="butt"/></pattern> </defs><g clip-path="url(#rounded-border)"><rect class="buffer hidden" height="3" width="110%" x="0" y="37" fill="url(#tiny-buffer)"/><rect class="loaded" height="3" width="0" x="0" y="37" fill="#666"/><rect class="played fill" height="3" width="0" x="0" y="37"/></g></svg></div><div class="play-icon"><svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" tabindex="-1"><polygon class="fill" points="1,0 20,10 1,20"/></svg></div><div class="pause-icon"><svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" tabindex="-1"><rect class="fill" width="6" height="20" x="0" y="0"/><rect class="fill" width="6" height="20" x="12" y="0"/></svg></div></button><div class="play-bar rounded-box"><div class="progress"><div class="buffer hidden"><svg width="110%" tabindex="-1"><defs> <pattern id="buffer" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 10 10"><line x1="5" y1="-1" x2="-5" y2="10" stroke-width="2" stroke="#666" stroke-linecap="butt"/><line x1="10" y1="-1" x2="0" y2="10" stroke-width="2" stroke="#666" stroke-linecap="butt"/><line x1="15" y1="-1" x2="5" y2="10" stroke-width="2" stroke="#666" stroke-linecap="butt"/></pattern> </defs><rect fill="url(#buffer)" width="100%" height="100%"/></svg></div><div class="loaded" role="progressbar" aria-label="загружено" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="180" aria-valuenow="0"></div><div class="played" role="progressbar" aria-label="воспроизведено" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="180" aria-valuenow="0"></div><div class="cuepoints"></div><div class="thumb-preview invisible hidden" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"><div class="thumb"></div></div><div class="ghost-timecode invisible hidden" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"><div class="box">00:00</div></div><div class="timecode" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"><div class="box">03:00</div></div></div>  <div class="volume" role="slider" aria-label="Громкость (изменяется с помощью кнопок курсора)" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="1" tabindex="0" aria-valuenow="1.000" aria-valuetext="100%"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>  <button class="hd" title="Выбрать качество видео" aria-label="HD"> <svg viewBox="0 0 102.717 47.035" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" tabindex="-1"><path class="fill" d="M100.014 6.758c-1.352-2.162-3.244-3.781-5.676-5.134-2.434-1.083-5.947-1.624-10.274-1.624h-21.625l-7.297 47.035h21.895c2.434 0 5.676-.274 8.92-1.352 2.434-.542 4.596-1.627 7.03-3.785 2.161-1.621 4.324-4.055 5.675-7.028 1.621-2.701 2.973-6.757 3.786-11.623.269-3.244.269-6.487.269-9.19-.54-2.704-1.352-5.138-2.703-7.299zm-12.433 16.76c-.541 3.783-1.352 6.485-2.165 8.109-1.08 1.893-2.162 2.703-3.782 3.514-1.083.541-3.515 1.082-6.217 1.082h-3.517l3.517-25.41h3.782c3.514 0 6.217.811 7.568 2.703 1.083 1.625 1.352 5.135.814 10.002z"/><path class="fill" d="M37.572,0L35.14,16.491H19.463L21.895,0H7.027L0,47.035h14.866l2.703-18.922h15.677l-2.971,18.922h14.866L52.439,0H37.572z"/></svg> </button>  <button class="hidden toggle effect off" title="Choose an effect to apply to the video"><svg viewBox="0 0 210 200" version="1.1"><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><circle class="red" fill="#f00" cx="63.5" cy="136.5" r="63.5"/><circle class="blue" fill="#2653ff" cx="146.5" cy="136.5" r="63.5"/><circle class="green" fill="#0f0" cx="104.5" cy="63.5" r="63.5"/></g></svg></button>  <button class="pip hidden enter" title="Включить режим “кадр-в-кадре”" data-title-enter="Включить режим “кадр-в-кадре”" data-title-return="Выключить режим “кадр-в-кадре”" hidden=""> <svg class="pip-icon" viewBox="0 0 16 12"><polygon class="fill" points="6 8 1 8 1 1 14 1 14 6 15 6 15 0 0 0 0 9 6 9 6 8"/><rect class="fill" x="7" y="7" width="9" height="5"/><polyline class="fill enter" transform="translate(4, 4) rotate(180) translate(-4, -4)" points="5.33 2 5.33 3 3.67 3 5.67 5 5 5.67 3 3.67 3 5.33 2 5.33 2 2"/><polyline class="fill return" points="5.33 2 5.33 3 3.67 3 5.67 5 5 5.67 3 3.67 3 5.33 2 5.33 2 2"/></svg> </button><button class="fullscreen" title="Перейти в полноэкранный режим" data-title-fullscreen="Перейти в полноэкранный режим" data-title-unfullscreen="Выйти из полноэкранного режима" aria-label="Полноэкранный режим"><div class="fullscreen-icon"><svg viewBox="0 0 12 12" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" tabindex="-1"><polyline class="fill" points="6,6 5.9,2 4.9,3 2.9,1 1,2.9 3,4.9 2,5.9" transform="translate(6,6)"/><polyline class="fill" points="6,6 5.9,2 4.9,3 2.9,1 1,2.9 3,4.9 2,5.9" transform="translate(6,6) rotate(90)"/><polyline class="fill" points="6,6 5.9,2 4.9,3 2.9,1 1,2.9 3,4.9 2,5.9" transform="translate(6,6) rotate(180)"/><polyline class="fill" points="6,6 5.9,2 4.9,3 2.9,1 1,2.9 3,4.9 2,5.9" transform="translate(6,6) rotate(270)"/></svg></div><div class="unfullscreen-icon"><svg viewBox="0 0 12 12" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" tabindex="-1"><polyline class="fill" points="-1,-1 -1.1,-5 -2.1,-4 -4.1,-6 -6,-4.1 -4,-2.1 -5,-1.1" transform="translate(6,6) "/><polyline class="fill" points="-1,-1 -1.1,-5 -2.1,-4 -4.1,-6 -6,-4.1 -4,-2.1 -5,-1.1" transform="translate(6,6) rotate(90)"/><polyline class="fill" points="-1,-1 -1.1,-5 -2.1,-4 -4.1,-6 -6,-4.1 -4,-2.1 -5,-1.1" transform="translate(6,6) rotate(180)"/><polyline class="fill" points="-1,-1 -1.1,-5 -2.1,-4 -4.1,-6 -6,-4.1 -4,-2.1 -5,-1.1" transform="translate(6,6) rotate(270)"/></svg></div></button>  <div class="logo">  <a href="https://vimeo.com/112497086" target="_blank" title="Смотреть на сайте vimeo.com" aria-label="Смотреть на сайте vimeo.com" data-clip-link=""> <svg viewBox="0 0 140 40" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" role="img" aria-label="Vimeo" tabindex="-1"><title>Vimeo</title><g><path class="fill logo-v" d="M31.277 18.832c-.14 3.052-2.27 7.229-6.39 12.531-4.259 5.536-7.863 8.306-10.811 8.306-1.825 0-3.371-1.687-4.633-5.059l-2.529-9.275c-.938-3.372-1.943-5.06-3.019-5.06-.234 0-1.054.494-2.458 1.477l-1.474-1.901c1.546-1.358 3.071-2.717 4.572-4.078 2.062-1.783 3.609-2.72 4.642-2.814 2.438-.234 3.938 1.433 4.502 5.001.608 3.851 1.03 6.246 1.266 7.182.704 3.195 1.476 4.791 2.321 4.791.657 0 1.641-1.037 2.954-3.108 1.312-2.072 2.015-3.649 2.109-4.732.188-1.789-.516-2.686-2.109-2.686-.75 0-1.522.173-2.318.514 1.54-5.044 4.481-7.495 8.823-7.355 3.22.095 4.737 2.184 4.552 6.266z"/><path class="fill logo-i" d="M50.613 28.713c-1.313 2.484-3.119 4.733-5.417 6.748-3.143 2.718-6.285 4.076-9.425 4.076-1.456 0-2.57-.469-3.343-1.406-.773-.938-1.137-2.153-1.09-3.653.045-1.548.526-3.938 1.441-7.173.914-3.232 1.373-4.967 1.373-5.201 0-1.218-.423-1.828-1.266-1.828-.282 0-1.079.494-2.393 1.477l-1.618-1.901c1.501-1.358 3.001-2.717 4.502-4.078 2.017-1.783 3.518-2.72 4.504-2.814 1.546-.14 2.684.314 3.411 1.367.726 1.052.996 2.417.81 4.098-.61 2.852-1.268 6.472-1.972 10.864-.046 2.01.681 3.014 2.182 3.014.656 0 1.827-.693 3.518-2.083 1.406-1.156 2.555-2.243 3.447-3.262l1.336 1.755zm-6.12-25.016c-.047 1.168-.633 2.288-1.76 3.361-1.266 1.212-2.767 1.82-4.501 1.82-2.672 0-3.963-1.166-3.869-3.499.045-1.213.76-2.381 2.144-3.501 1.384-1.119 2.919-1.68 4.609-1.68.984 0 1.805.387 2.462 1.155.656.772.961 1.553.915 2.344z"/><path class="fill logo-m" d="M94.543 28.713c-1.314 2.484-3.117 4.733-5.416 6.748-3.145 2.718-6.285 4.076-9.426 4.076-3.051 0-4.527-1.687-4.432-5.06.045-1.501.338-3.306.877-5.415.539-2.108.832-3.748.879-4.921.049-1.779-.492-2.673-1.623-2.673-1.223 0-2.682 1.456-4.375 4.362-1.788 3.05-2.754 6.003-2.894 8.861-.095 2.02.103 3.568.592 4.645-3.272.096-5.565-.444-6.873-1.617-1.171-1.032-1.708-2.742-1.614-5.135.045-1.501.276-3.001.69-4.502.414-1.5.644-2.837.69-4.011.095-1.734-.54-2.604-1.9-2.604-1.177 0-2.444 1.339-3.806 4.011-1.361 2.673-2.113 5.465-2.253 8.371-.094 2.627.074 4.456.503 5.486-3.219.096-5.505-.582-6.857-2.035-1.122-1.214-1.634-3.06-1.539-5.54.044-1.214.258-2.911.645-5.084.386-2.175.603-3.87.647-5.087.093-.841-.119-1.263-.633-1.263-.281 0-1.079.475-2.393 1.424l-1.687-1.901c.234-.184 1.71-1.545 4.432-4.078 1.969-1.828 3.306-2.766 4.009-2.812 1.219-.095 2.204.409 2.954 1.511s1.126 2.38 1.126 3.834c0 .469-.047.915-.14 1.336.703-1.077 1.523-2.017 2.463-2.814 2.156-1.874 4.572-2.931 7.245-3.166 2.298-.187 3.938.352 4.925 1.617.795 1.033 1.17 2.511 1.125 4.433.329-.28.681-.586 1.056-.915 1.078-1.267 2.133-2.273 3.164-3.023 1.736-1.267 3.541-1.97 5.418-2.112 2.25-.187 3.867.35 4.852 1.611.844 1.028 1.219 2.5 1.127 4.415-.047 1.309-.363 3.213-.949 5.712-.588 2.501-.879 3.936-.879 4.31-.049.982.047 1.659.279 2.034.236.373.797.559 1.689.559.656 0 1.826-.693 3.518-2.083 1.406-1.156 2.555-2.243 3.447-3.262l1.337 1.757z"/><path class="fill logo-e" d="M120.922 28.642c-1.361 2.249-4.033 4.495-8.02 6.743-4.971 2.856-10.012 4.284-15.125 4.284-3.797 0-6.52-1.267-8.16-3.797-1.172-1.735-1.734-3.797-1.688-6.189.045-3.797 1.736-7.407 5.064-10.832 3.658-3.75 7.973-5.627 12.945-5.627 4.596 0 7.033 1.873 7.314 5.615.188 2.384-1.125 4.842-3.938 7.368-3.004 2.76-6.781 4.515-11.328 5.263.842 1.169 2.109 1.752 3.799 1.752 3.375 0 7.059-.855 11.045-2.574 2.859-1.207 5.111-2.461 6.754-3.76l1.338 1.754zm-15.969-7.345c.045-1.259-.469-1.89-1.547-1.89-1.406 0-2.83.969-4.283 2.906-1.451 1.936-2.201 3.789-2.248 5.562-.025 0-.025.305 0 .911 2.295-.839 4.287-2.122 5.971-3.849 1.357-1.491 2.06-2.707 2.107-3.64z"/><path class="fill logo-o" d="M140.018 23.926c-.189 4.31-1.781 8.031-4.783 11.169-3.002 3.137-6.73 4.706-11.186 4.706-3.705 0-6.52-1.195-8.441-3.585-1.404-1.777-2.182-4.001-2.32-6.668-.236-4.029 1.217-7.729 4.361-11.101 3.377-3.746 7.619-5.618 12.732-5.618 3.281 0 5.766 1.102 7.457 3.301 1.594 2.015 2.32 4.614 2.18 7.796zm-7.95-.264c.047-1.269-.129-2.434-.527-3.49-.4-1.057-.975-1.587-1.725-1.587-2.391 0-4.361 1.293-5.906 3.877-1.316 2.115-2.02 4.371-2.111 6.766-.049 1.176.164 2.21.633 3.104.514 1.032 1.242 1.549 2.182 1.549 2.109 0 3.914-1.244 5.416-3.735 1.267-2.068 1.945-4.23 2.038-6.484z"/></g></svg> </a>  </div> </div> </div><div class="sidedock" role="toolbar"> <div class="box"><label class="rounded-box like-label invisible" role="presentation"><span>Нравится</span></label><button class="like-button rounded-box" aria-label="Нравится" data-label-add="Нравится" data-label-add-logged-out="Нравится (открывается в новом окне)" data-label-remove="Снять отметку “Нравится”"> <svg class="like-icon" viewBox="0 0 110 81" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" tabindex="-1"><path class="fill" d="M82.496 1c-14.698 0-25.969 11.785-27.496 13.457-1.526-1.672-12.798-13.457-27.494-13.457-16.299 0-27.506 15.037-27.506 27.885 0 12.795 12.562 22.558 22.245 27.592 9.186 4.771 30.601 18.349 32.755 24.523 2.154-6.174 23.57-19.752 32.755-24.523 9.684-5.034 22.245-14.797 22.245-27.592 0-12.848-11.206-27.885-27.504-27.885z"/></svg> </button></div> <div class="box"><label class="rounded-box hidden watch-later-label invisible" role="presentation"><span>Посмотреть позже</span></label><button class="watch-later-button rounded-box" aria-label="Посмотреть позже" data-label-add="Посмотреть позже" data-label-add-logged-out="Посмотреть позже (открывается в новом окне)" data-label-remove="Удалить из списка “Посмотреть позже”"> <svg class="watch-later-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" tabindex="-1"><polyline class="fill hour-hand" points="9.64,4.68 10.56,4.68 11.28,11.21 8.93,11.21 9.64,4.68"/><polyline class="fill minute-hand" points="14.19,13.65 13.7,14.14 8.58,10.4 10.44,8.5 14.19,13.65"/><circle class="stroke" cx="10" cy="10" r="8" stroke-width="2"/></svg> </button></div> <div class="box"><label class="rounded-box hidden share-label invisible" role="presentation"><span>Поделиться</span></label><button class="share-button rounded-box" aria-label="Поделиться"> <svg class="share-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" tabindex="-1"><polygon class="fill" points="20,0 0,12 5,15 17,4 7,16 7,19 9,17 14,20"/></svg> </button></div></div></div><div class="overlay-wrapper hidden" hidden=""><div class="overlay-cell"><div class="overlay" role="dialog" aria-live="assertive"></div><div class="overlay-icon-wrapper hidden"><div class="overlay-icon"></div></div><div class="overlay-logo logo"></div></div><nav><button class="back cloaked" aria-label="Назад"><svg class="icon-back" viewBox="0 0 64 64" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" tabindex="-1"><path class="fill" d="M0 32l32 32v-20h32l0-24h-32v-20z"/></svg></button><button class="close" aria-label="Закрыть наложение"><svg class="icon-close" viewBox="0 0 64 64" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" tabindex="-1"><path class="fill" d="M60 48.796l-16.812-16.796 16.812-16.796-11.204-11.204-16.796 16.804-16.804-16.804-11.196 11.204 16.796 16.796-16.796 16.796 11.196 11.204 16.804-16.804 16.796 16.804z"/></svg></button></nav></div><div class="notification-wrapper hidden" hidden=""><div class="notification-cell"><div class="notification" role="dialog" aria-live="assertive"></div></div></div><div class="stats-debug rounded-box hidden" aria-hidden="true" hidden=""><p><span class="stats-debug-label">Clip ID:</span><span class="stats-debug-value stats-debug-clip-id">112497086</span></p><p><span class="stats-debug-label">Delivery:</span><span class="stats-debug-value stats-debug-delivery">progressive</span></p><p><span class="stats-debug-label">Playing:</span><span class="stats-debug-value stats-debug-resolution">360p@25</span></p><p><span class="stats-debug-label">Embed size:</span><span class="stats-debug-value stats-debug-dimensions">852×682 </span></p><p><span class="stats-debug-label">CDN:</span><span class="stats-debug-value stats-debug-cdn">level3</span></p><p><span class="stats-debug-label">Tests:</span><span class="stats-debug-value stats-debug-test-group">cdn_switch: 0</span></p><button class="stats-debug-close" aria-label="Close stats debug panel"><svg class="icon-close" viewBox="0 0 64 64" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" tabindex="-1"><path class="fill" d="M60 48.796l-16.812-16.796 16.812-16.796-11.204-11.204-16.796 16.804-16.804-16.804-11.196 11.204 16.796 16.796-16.796 16.796 11.196 11.204 16.804-16.804 16.796 16.804z"/></svg></button><input class="stats-debug-code" type="text"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="stats-debug-copy" target="_blank">Open link</a></div><div role="alertdialog" aria-label="Alert" aria-atomic="true" class="player-alert hidden" hidden=""><button data-close="" aria-label="Close alert" class="close"><svg class="icon-close" viewBox="0 0 64 64" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" tabindex="-1"><path class="fill" d="M60 48.796l-16.812-16.796 16.812-16.796-11.204-11.204-16.796 16.804-16.804-16.804-11.196 11.204 16.796 16.796-16.796 16.796 11.196 11.204 16.804-16.804 16.796 16.804z"/></svg></button></div></div>
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, сразу не сказал, что меня интересует не фоновое видео, а в портфолио.

Comment: Добавил в ответ

Comment: Я хочу добиться такого же внешнего вида, Я понимаю, что видео берется с vimeo. Сам внешний вид каким образом получается, мне не совсем понятно. Думал может быть какой нибудь плагин js